# Site Navigation not visible to Site collection admin after Target Audience settings

Tags: 2013, audience-targeting, global-navigation

I have a site where I am adding custom navigation in site navigation.

When I add target audience for some links, this links are visible to that audience only. But I want is to show this links to Site collection Administrator too which is not visible default.

Is there a way to visible these links to site collection admin without creating a new group and add this to target audience?

Answer (score 0):

No, Target Audience takes only those group which are added in there. that's the whole purpose of Target Audience. You can create a separate group and add the Admins in there and then add that group in target Audience